# How can I call a function/action when a statusItem is clicked?

Tags: macos, swift

I have this code that opens up a popover element at the "sender" location, i.e. the button that was pressed. How can I make this function call when a statusItem is clicked, so that the popover comes down from the status/menu bar?

```
@IBAction func togglePopover(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !(popoverIsOpen) {
        myPopover.showRelativeToRect(sender.bounds, ofView: popoverButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge(3))
        popoverIsOpen = true
    }
    else {
        myPopover.close()
        popoverIsOpen = false
    }
}
```

I am currently using `NSPopover` and `NSStatusItem`.

**edit:** The changelog for Xcode 6 beta 4 added `NSStatusItem.button` and softly deprecated the previous form of calls like `NSStatusItem.action`, `NSStatusItem.title`, `NSStatusItem.target`, etc.

The documentation now reads

> `NSStatusItem.button`
>
> > The button that is displayed in the status bar. This is created automatically on the creation of the StatusItem. Behavior customization for the button, such as image, target/action, tooltip, can be set with this property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reach an implementation shown below, using the new NSStatusBarButton visual representation of an NSStatusBarItem. In this example, my .xib file has the `NSPopover` element already connected to a view, which isn't shown here.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPopover: NSPopover!
var statusBar: NSStatusItem!
var popoverIsOpen = false

@IBAction func togglePopover(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !(popoverIsOpen) {
        myPopover.showRelativeToRect(sender.bounds, ofView: statusBar.button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge(3))
        popoverIsOpen = true
    }
    else {
        myPopover.close()
        popoverIsOpen = false
    }
}

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    //initialize menu bar icon
    statusBar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(CGFloat(48))
    statusBar.button.title = "Your App Title"
    statusBar.button.appearsDisabled = false
    statusBar.button.action = Selector("togglePopover:")
    statusBar.button.target = self
}
```