# Update NSStatusItem title when NSStatusItem button is clicked

Tags: swift, macos

In Swift how would I update the title text of an NSStatusItem object when the button of the object is clicked?

To provide some context to the problem. I have a swift app that displays the public IP address of your client in the menu bar, when the menu bar button is clicked I want the IP address to be updated.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private var statusItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    
        Task {
            do {
                let myip: String = try await checkIp()
                statusItem.button?.title = myip.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func checkIp() async throws -> String {
        let url = URL(string: "https://checkip.amazonaws.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        return String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I call a function/action when a statusItem is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964938/how-can-i-call-a-function-action-when-a-statusitem-is-clicked)